# Jquery File Upload using cgi

Tags: perl, cgi, jquery-file-upload

I am new to perl scripting.I am working on drag and drop file upload and using jquery file upload.I'll appreciate if you can help me in installing this perl module and how to use it.

I am trying to follow readme file but while doing "Perl Makefile.pl" some warnings are there

```
Warning: prerequisite Image::Magick 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite JSON::XS 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Net::SSH2 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Net::SSH2::SFTP 0 not found.
WARNING: Setting ABSTRACT via file 'lib/jQuery/File/Upload.pm' failed
 at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 609
Writing Makefile for jQuery::File::Upload
```

Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json

i am not sure if it is installed or not.

Please help me for implementation.

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It failed or you will likely gets problems anyway, and you will likely need to install the packages mentioned in the errors. You may also need to install some ssl dev lib bits. For example on mine (Linux Mint/Ubuntu), I needed to do the following...

```
#edit, looks like on yours you need to install Image::Magick as well
sudo cpan JSON::XS
sudo apt-get install libssh2-1-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo cpan Net::SSH2
```

Note: the above packages you may want to see if you can find via your package manager rather than CPAN, however the above should steer you in the right direction of the things you probably need.

then back to the README

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

Comment: What OS/system are you on ? It its on a redhat based system it will probably use YUM to install packages.

Comment: ok Thanks. I am on centos so i am using yum now but "No package libssh2-1-dev available.". i am also getting error while installing imageMagick using "sudo cpan Image::Magick" in Magick.xs file.
".

Comment: Try libssh2-devel.i686 or libssh2-devel.x86_64 depending on architecture. Image::Magick can sometimes be a bit fiddly, these docs may help http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php

Comment: i am still to install libssh2 but still have not get it's repo so i can install it using yum.

Comment: Didn't quite understand, did you try yum install libssh2-devel.i686  libssh2.i686 or yum install libssh2-devel.x86_64 libssh2.x86_64 as example ?

Comment: I tried it using yum for x86_64.but there was no repo for it.Finally able to install it after adding right repository.one last thing i am facing is "WARNING: Setting ABSTRACT via file 'lib/jQuery/File/Upload.pm' failed
 at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 609
"

Comment: I am not sure that is anything serious, it sounds like you have installed it ok now. See if it works first.